# Simple integral $\displaystyle\int \frac{e^x}{x^2-a^2}\ dx$

Tags: integration

Is this integral solvable?
$$\int \frac{e^x}{x^2-a^2}dx,\quad a>0.$$

Comment: The anti-derivative is not an elementary function.

Comment: It is not an elementary integral. You can have a closed form solution in terms of the exponential integral.

Comment: How do you know? Proof?

Comment: Is this true? $\int\frac{e^x}{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{e^{a+i(x-a)}-e^{-a+i(x+a)}}{2a}$. How?

Comment: It involves this: http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralEi/ so, in other words, not solvable.

Comment: @David: The answer is in terms of the "exponential integral function" not "the exponential function". See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428950/explicit-formula-for-the-series-sum-k-1-infty-fracxkk-cdot-k).

Comment: Yeah! You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2-a^2=(x-a)(x+a)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\dfrac1{x^2-a^2}=\dfrac1{2a}\left(\dfrac1{x-a}-\dfrac1{x+a}\right)$$

\begin{alignat*}{9}
\int\frac{e^x}{x^2-a^2}dx\ &=\dfrac1{2a}\bigg(&&\int\dfrac{e^x}{x-a}dx&-&&&\int\dfrac{e^x}{x+a}dx&\bigg)\\
&=\dfrac1{2a}\bigg(&e^a&\int\dfrac{e^{x-a}}{x-a}dx&-&&\ e^{-a}&\int\dfrac{e^{x+a}}{x+a}dx&\bigg)\\
&=\dfrac1{2a}\bigg[&e^a&\int\dfrac{e^{x-a}}{x-a}d(x-a)\ &-&&\ e^{-a}&\int\dfrac{e^{x+a}}{x+a}d(x+a)&\bigg]\\
&=\frac1{2a}\Big[&e^a\,&\text{Ei}(x-a)&-&&\ e^{-a}\,&\text{Ei}(x+a)&\Big]
\end{alignat*}

where Ei$(x)$ is the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), which is not expressible in terms of elementary functions. See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more details.